# Performance of regex alteration

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex

The actual regex is more complex, but I am surprised by the cost of adding a second word:

```
import timeit
SETUP = "import re; STRING = ' ' * 100000"

print(min(timeit.Timer("re.findall(r'(foo)'        , STRING)", SETUP).repeat(10, 1000)))
print(min(timeit.Timer("re.findall(r'(foo|bar)'    , STRING)", SETUP).repeat(10, 1000)))
print(min(timeit.Timer("re.findall(r'(foo|bar|qux)', STRING)", SETUP).repeat(10, 1000)))
```

The second regex is **15 times slower**, while the third one is **faster** than the second one (using *3.10.2*).

```
0.012617316999239847
0.18311264598742127
0.146542029993725
```

The difference [here](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/online-compiler/) (*3.11.8*) is even worse:

```
0.022139030000005278
0.8239181079999867
0.6327433810000116
```

Any insight why the second version is so much slower, even slower than the third?
Is there a way to improve that speed?

Pre-compiling the regex and using non-capturing groups does not make much of a difference.

Update: [PyPI regex](https://pypi.org/project/regex/) is more consistent, but slower. Also a large difference between one/two words:

```
0.022885548998601735
0.25088962000154424
0.2537434719997691
```

Comment: Just to note, *all* regexes get pre-compiled and cached. The point of using `re.compile` is to store the compiled regex somewhere explicitly, where it won't get kicked out of the private cache if you use lots of regexes in your program.

Comment: @chepner: I know, thanks! Just wanted to get that out of the way since the behavior does not yet make sense to me.

Comment: Interestingly, I can't reproduce this on Python 3.12 and 3.13a4. On 3.11, a regex with 6 branches is even slower than 3 and is the slowest overall.

Comment: @InSync: How much slower are two words compared to one?

Comment: Use PyPi `regex` library, it is more consistent.

Comment: @PeterLang 2 is, as expected, still much slower than 1, but every number from 2 to 9 sits nicely along each other. 2 is generally faster by a tiny bit, but not much.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: Thanks, updated the question with timing for PyPi regex.

Comment: However, I do not see a problem. Whenever `|` appears, it triggers backtracking when matching, and backtracking is a mechanism that we love but that comes at a cost. Any specific implementation efficiency can be different.